# Finding files that have a numeric suffix in Python

Tags: python

Prefacing this by saying I'm completely new to Python, but not new to programming.

I've been experimenting with glob.glob in compiling lists of file names for further analysis.

I have files that follow a format like the following:

- File 1.csv
- File 2.csv
- File 3.csv
- ...

Right now, I check files using

```
glob.glob("File ?.csv")
```

However, I just realized that this will no longer work when I reach File 10, as the '?' wildcard only substitutes 1 character.

Outside of having to rename those files to fit the number of digits (ex: formatting file 3 to 03, if the number of files is > 10 but < 100), what are some ways I can accommodate the additional numbers?

I can anticipate the number of files to a certain extent, but the number can be anywhere from one, to ten, and even into the hundreds.

Comment: Can there be `File non_digits`?

Comment: It will always follow the 
    File some_number format (Ex: no File 1A, File AB2, File B_A, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot match an arbitrary amount of digits with glob, if you wanted to specifically match `File some_digits.csv` you will need a regex:

```
import glob
import re
import os
patt = re.compile(r"File \d+\.csv")
for f in os.listdir("."):
    if patt.match(f):
        print(f)
```

If you were sure that if there was one digit then that was a match you could use `File [0-9]*.csv` which would make sure there was one digit:

```
import glob

glob.glob("/path_to/File [0-9]*.csv"))
```

Of course that would match `File 1abc.csv` also but your current `"File ?.csv"` would match `File a.csv` etc.. which is not numeric.

Comment: Very helpful, but I do have a question: `patt = re.compile(r"File \d+\.csv")` has an additional backslash after the regex; is that normal?

Comment: @Sven, `.` has a special meaning in the regex, if you just had `.` it would match any character excluding a newline so we need to escape it to match a literal `.`.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think to check if it needed to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in two steps:

```
import glob
import re

# First match all files which fit the general pattern (will match things
# like "File name without numbers.csv"
gross_match = glob.glob("File *.csv")
# Filter the list with a precise regular expression
my_files = [fname for fname in gross_match if match("File [0-9]+.csv", fname)]
```

Performance can be improved by precompiling the regex.

Comment: This isn't DRY. The first step should just be `os.listdir` or `glob.glob('*')`.

Comment: Unless of course the directory contains a huge number of files which could match `glob('*')`. This gets one selective list that is as small as possible, then filters it.

Comment: If you wanted to save memory you could use `iglob` and filter that